# Creating and designing checkboxes from an Array in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am struggling with trying to create and bootstrap design a simple survey in rails 4. A user (client) has many surveys through recordings. We intend to ask the user to fill out a completely new survey every so often so each client will have an archive of completed surveys. My models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recordings
  has_many :surveys, through: recordings

#########

class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recordings
  has_many :users, through: :recordings

#########

class Recording < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :survey
```

Possible Issue #1: I decided that I did not need to separate the survey into survey has_many questions and questions has_many answers. The questions are static for each survey, so, my opinion was that each survey just needed standard column entries as if it were any other form.

So, with that said, I did something like this for the survey questions (sample survey with 1 question).

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
 # ...

FAVORITE_FOODS = %w[pizza steak salad hotdogs pasta pancakes]
 #....

def self.favorite_foods
  FAVORITE_FOODS
end
```

Then in controller:

```
class Survey < ApplicationController

  def new
    @survey = current_user.surveys.build
    @foods = Survey.favorite_foods
  end

  def create
    @survey = current_user.surveys.build(survey_params)
      if @survey.save
          redirect_to surveys_path, notice: "Thank you for filling out our client survey."
      else
         flash[:notice] = "Your survey has not been completed."
         render 'new'
      end
  end

  #....standard crud for has_many

  private

  def survey_params
    params.require(:survey).permit({:favorite_foods => []},....
  end
```

Then finally on the view:

```
 <%= form_for [@user, @survey] do |f| %>

 <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
     <h5>What are your favorite foods?</h5>
        <div class="btn-group"><h6>
    <%  @foods.each do |food| %>
      <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="button"><%= check_box_tag "food_array[]", food %> <%= food %></button>

<% end %></h6><%= f.submit%>
```

Question/Issue:

I have a functional problem and a design problem.

1. My current code is broken and clicking on the check_box and then submitting the form renders the form back to me.
2. The buttons have a check_box on them, but I want the buttons to serve as the checkboxes themselves.

I have watched this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes
but didn't think I needed to do an extra action in the controller for my case. Let me know.